# Closest Number to two other numbers while maintaing ratio

Tags: ratio, programming

I wanted to essentially compute the scaling factor of 2 numbers, based on two other numbers (I am unable to describe it well).

Eg:

Lets say I have an image of size 200x300 (aspect is 2:3) and I need to find a ratio that is that is closest to another ratio, lets say 4:5.

Now normally I would just multiply to find the ratio keeping one of the numbers common, so in this case the ratio would become 4:6 (multiplying 2 and 3 with 2).

But I would like a method that would give me numbers with the ratio 2 : 3, but closer to 4 and 5, for eg., if I would have multiplied by 1.9 then the ratio would be 3.8 : 5.7, whose total difference from the previous ratio would be less than that of 4 : 6 (My heuristic for total difference is |(4-x)|+|(5-y)|, which in the case of 4 : 6 => 1, and with 3.8 : 5.7 => 0.9)

In essence, I need some kind of method to find those numbers which give that minimum gap.
If someone has a better heuristic as well I would also be interested in that

PS:This will need to be implemented in Javascript, so if you have some code I could use I would greatly appreciate it, obviously this would be extra and totally not expected.

Thank you

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but a few new concepts need to be ironed out. Are you wanting to exactly preserve the ratio, or is this "image" able to be stretched (in essence can the ratio be slightly changed). If it's the first case, then you have a formula of $difference = |4-2x| + |5-3x|$. Minimizing this gives the idea value of multiplying by 1.667 (giving a total difference of 0.667). Perhaps it'd be better to explain the exactly what you'd like in terms of image scaling, and then we can come up with a method for that.

Comment: Optimizing a function with absolute values is not the simplest. Why not to tahe for example $(4-2x)^2+(5-3x)^2$ and the solution is explicit.. For this option, you would get $x=\frac{23}{13}=1.77$ instead of $x=\frac 53=1.67$.

Comment: Claude Leibovici makes a good point about the way to calculate the difference. Using absolute values is the equivalent of finding the distance between 2 corners on right triangle by adding the length of the sides, instead of calculating the length of the hypotenuse.

Comment: Thanks @claude and caedmon, treating it as a quadratic makes the most sense. With regards to the purpose, basically I have a 3D mesh which is only sized using it's scaling factor, and an image is then rendered onto it. The scaling factor initially chosen is good for representing the size it should be on the screen, however when a new texture is used, which will be close to it in aspect ratio, I want the length and height to change by a minimum amount, hence this requirement